# Framework for SMTP Sending with iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, smtp

I wonder if there is any good framework / library out there for sending eMail via SMTP using iOS 5.x

I've tried SKSMTPMessage already and is not that robust as expected.

Any help will be appreciated.

Regards,

Christian

Comment: There appears to be a commercial SMTP component here: http://www.chilkatsoft.com/email-features.asp (I am not affiliated in any way; though, I was a happy customer in the past for non-iOS components)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

have you already tried [MailCore](https://github.com/mronge/MailCore) ?

> MailCore is a Mac and iOS framework designed to ease the pain of
>   dealing with e-mail protocols. MailCore makes the process of sending
>   e-mail easy by hiding the nasty details like MIME composition from
>   you. Instead, there is a nice interface for composing messages and
>   then there is a single method required to send the message. Checking
>   e-mail on an IMAP server is a more complex beast, but MailCore makes
>   the job much simpler but presenting everything as a set of abstract
>   objects like Messages, Folders and Accounts.